# IntelliJ Not Displaying Values in Debug Mode

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, groovy

For the last weeks, I am having problems when debugging in IntelliJ (java/groovy) and I am not able to see the values of the different variables.

I see "head", "tail", "accessorder". In each of these entries I can access the key / value of separately. Therefore, in order to see the complete item (e.g hashmap or arraylist), I need to open each entry separately, which is very inefficient.

This description may not be clear, so I include a screenshot of what I currently see.

[image: debug mode]

I have tried the following:

- Resetting the settings
- Using IntelliJ 2020 version (having deleted the settings and cache)
- Using IntelliJ 2021 version (having deleted the settings and cache)

Thank you,
Kat

---

After having tried @Satyen Shimpi useful reply, I am not able to change the view type in the variables.
[image]

Comment: Please check that "Enable alternative view for Collections classes" is checked under "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried with both options, but the outcome was completely the same. I also checked the comments from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-672

Comment: @katherine99 please try my suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I think your settings are showing the *Map* as `Object` and you need to change the view settings to `Auto`.
Following will help you.
The reason you are seeing the head, tail etc is
[image]
From Above, you can see that LinkedHashMap is being rendered as `Object` in `View as` menu because I had selected `Object`

---

And you can solve it by changing `View` to `Auto`. Then it will show Map in a way that you are expecting where you don't need to expand each entry.
[image]

Note: When you select `Auto`, it will automatically change to `Map`. For the same reason, my image has `Map` checked and not the `Auto`

Comment: @katherine99
I am using Intellij 2021.2.1. But I guess its available in all Intellij version.

Comment: Thank @ Satyen Shimpi for the help and the screenshots. However, I am not able to change the "View as" option and it is deactivated. Do you have any idea why this could be the case?(I have the default settings). Image included below the initial post